# How to get rid of Sequence in the arguments of a DownValue generated at runtime

Tags: functions, function-construction, hold

I have the following function to create DownValues for some symbol when desired:

```
str = "p"; int = 5;

SetAttributes[addDownValuesRuntime, HoldAll];
addDownValuesRuntime[func_Symbol, args__, body_] := With[{arg = Unevaluated[args]},
SetDelayed @@ Hold[func[arg], body]
];
```

If I make my function definition such that the `args` are encapsulated by braces i.e. `{str_String, int_Integer}` I note that the arguments for the defined function `f` are also encapsulated by `{ }` :

```
addDownValuesRuntime[f, {str_String, int_Integer}, {str,int}];
??f
(* f[{str_String,int_Integer}]:= {str,int} *)
```

However, if I make my definition like this (args not encapsulated) then the `args` are inside `Sequence` and I cannot   :

```
addDownValuesRuntime[f, str, int, {str,int}];
??f
(* f[Sequence[str,int]]:= {str,int} *)
```

In this case I cannot use the function.

**My question is how to get rid of `Sequence` such that my final function definition looks like `f[str_String,int_Integer]:= body;` or `f[str,int]:= body`**

Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: No need to get rid of `Sequence` since `f[Sequence[str,int]]:= {str,int}` is equivalent to `f[str,int]:= {str,int}`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I am not able to use `f[1,2]` after function definition. it is evaluating to itself.

Comment: Indeed, that's puzzling since `f[Sequence[str_String, int_Integer]] := {str, int}` and `f[str_String, int_Integer] := {str, int}` produce perfectly the same function. `SetDelayed` has the rather seldom attribute `SequenceHold`. Must be related to that. Btw.: Why don't you use `addDownValuesRuntime[func_Symbol, args__, body_] := 
  SetDelayed[func[args], body];`?

Comment: Instead of `addDownValuesRuntime[f, a1, a2,..., b]]`, why not `f[a1, a2,...] := b`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks ! was somehow challenging myself :)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher found a fix. kindly check the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClearAll[addDownValuesRuntime, f]

str = "p"; int = 5; (* global values defined to test if our code binds the definition to
function f without evaluating these OwnValues *)

SetAttributes[addDownValuesRuntime, HoldAll];
addDownValuesRuntime[func_Symbol, {args__}, body_] := 
Block[{setdelayed = SetDelayed},
SetAttributes[setdelayed, HoldAll];
Apply[setdelayed,{func[GeneralUtilities`HoldSymbolName /@ Unevaluated[args]] /. 
  GeneralUtilities`HoldSymbolName[x___] :> x, Unevaluated@body}
 ]
];
```

To test if the code works properly (sanity checks):

```
addDownValuesRuntime[f, {str, int}, {str, int}];

?f
(* f[str,int]:={str,int} *)  (* as expected the body and arguments did not
evaluate prematurely *)
```

Furthermore,named patterns seem to work fine as well:

```
addDownValuesRuntime[f, {str_String, int_Integer}, {str, int}];
(* f[str_String,int_String] := {str,int} *)
```

**calling the functions**

```
f["string", 2]
(* {"string", 2} *)

f[str, int]
(* {"p", 5} *)
```

Comment: actually in the above code we do not need to even define `setdelayed`. `SetDelayed` works equally fine !

Comment: Have you tried calling your `f` with the new definition you added?

Comment: @halirutan seems to be working fine. let me add it

Answer (score 5):

What is wrong with

```
ClearAll[addDownValuesRuntime];
SetAttributes[addDownValuesRuntime, HoldAll];
addDownValuesRuntime[func_Symbol, args__, body_] := (func[args] := body);
```

?

Comment: if you do this with the above code: `addDownValuesRuntime[f, {str, int}, {str, int}]` then we get a premature evaluation of the arguments of the function. `f[{p,5}]:={str,int}`. It is not a great deal though since any global definitions will eventually cause the definition to result in the same value. I was deliberately avoiding this solution on purpose. +1 nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it is useful to do what you asked for, but in my opinion a simpler method would be:

```
SetAttributes[addDownValuesRuntime,HoldAll];
addDownValuesRuntime[func_Symbol,args__, body_]:=With[{old=Attributes[func]},
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        SetAttributes[func,HoldAll],
        SetDelayed[func[args],body],
        Attributes[func]=old
    ]
]
```

For your "evaluation" leak example:

```
str = "p"; int = 5;

addDownValuesRuntime[f, str, int, {str, int}]

DownValues[f]
```

> {HoldPattern[f[str, int]] :> {str, int}}